# How to validate user input in C#?

Tags: c#, validation, input

I’m trying to ask the user to input a number 1-10 and validate their response.

I’m new to C# I’m learning it in a class I’m taking and don’t have any background in programming. Having difficulties remembering all the terms and their uses

```
Console.Writeline(“Enter a number between 1-10”) 

String (num1) 
{ 
case “one”: 
case “two”: 
case “three”: 
Console.Writeline(“Picked number 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, or 10”);
break;
```

Comment: Are you talking about [switch statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-switch-statement)?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what type of validation you're doing? Explain it in English rather than code, and give example inputs and outputs. Then correlate your code attempt (which, please format with a [code block]) against your requirements.

Comment: @kuga: Please do not suggest this is a simple question. To you it might be, to others people is might not be.  Also referring to Chatbot is not advised, because asking a question correctly there determines the correctness of the answer, but be prepared to get a non-meaning-full answer when you are the question in the wrong way.   So, a better suggestion, is to take the class (all of them) and then start asking here on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2):

A common way would be with a helper method, the exact design may vary, but this would be a fairly simple option that lets the user retry entering numbers :

```
public static int ReadInt(string question, int min = int.MinValue, int max = int.MaxValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine(question);
    while(true){
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if(!int.TryParse(input, out var number)){
            Console.WriteLine("Not an integer, try again");
            continue;
        }
        if(number < min){
            Console.WriteLine($" {number} smaller than {min}, try again");
            continue;
        }
        if(number > max){
            Console.WriteLine($" {number} larger than {max}, try again");
            continue;
        }
        return number ;
    }    
}
```

If you want to accept input like "one" instead of "1", you might want to consider creating your own parsing method as well. But this can easily get complicated for any large or negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out NuGet package [Spectre.Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spectre.Console/0.46.0?_src=template) with [documentation](https://spectreconsole.net/).

The following does not teach the basics like @jonasH so you might want to go with there reply if that is the case, otherwise continue here.

Here is an example were the method `GetInt` provides

- Type of input `new TextPrompt<int>` see more [here](https://spectreconsole.net/prompts/text)
- Text to provide user instructions
- `ValidationErrorMessage` a message for entering the wrong type e.g. string instead of int.
- `Validate` is used to return an error message if the input is out of the range or indicates with `ValidationResult.Success()` input was in range.

The method `Choices` is responsible for outputting text to the value returned from `GetInt`

```
internal partial class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dictionary = Choices();

        Console.WriteLine($"You selected {dictionary[GetInt()]}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Text for int selected in <see cref="GetInt"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Text for int selected</returns>
    private static Dictionary<int, string> Choices()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            { 1, "one" }, { 2, "two" }, { 3, "three" }, { 4, "four" }, { 5, "five" },
            { 6, "six" }, { 7, "seven" }, { 8, "eight" }, { 9, "nine" }, { 10, "ten" },
            { 11, "none" },
        };
        return dictionary;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a prompt for an int between two numbers with
    /// - colorization of screen output
    /// - Validation to ensure input is within set range
    /// - Range is 1 to 10 with 11 as an exit for aborting
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>User selection</returns>
    private static int GetInt() =>
        AnsiConsole.Prompt(new TextPrompt<int>(
                "Picked a [cyan]number[/] between [b]1[/] and [b]10[/] or [b]11[/] to exit")
                .PromptStyle("cyan")
                .ValidationErrorMessage("[red]That's not a valid value[/]")
                .Validate(validator: x => x switch
                {
                    <= 0 => ValidationResult.Error("[red]1 is min value[/]"),
                    >= 12 => ValidationResult.Error("[red]11 is max value[/]"),
                    _ => ValidationResult.Success(),
                }));
}
```

[image]